# Problem Displaying Swagger-UI After Spring Library Update

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

We have a webapp(war) that embeds the Swagger UI working under Spring Boot 2.7.5 and springdoc-openapi 1.6.14. I am in the process of updating Spring Boot to 2.7.11 and all is working fine. When I try to update springdoc-openapi to 1.6.16 I see this error:

```
Unable to render this definition

The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).
```

After reading through the posts of people with the same problem, I started with hitting the /v3/api-docs URL, all I see is a long series of characters (kind of like an encrypted string). I switched back to springdoc-openapi 1.6.14 and hit /v3/api-docs and a valid json was returned. Then I tried springdoc-openapi 1.7.0 and it also exhibits the behavior of returning a long string of characters.

I need to solve the Swagger-UI display issue. I looked at the Swagger-ui projects but I am not familiar with React and js.

Answer (score 1):

seems that your service's http message converters configuration may not contain `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`.
If you provided your own message converters configuration, make sure it is there and it is added *before* `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

See this [springdoc issue report](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/2143#issuecomment-1474981955) for reference